# Node Js sequelize select query by month

Tags: node.js, select, orm, sequelize.js

Am new in `Node Js`, In my `Node Js` project am using `sequelize ORM` with `MySql` database.

This is my query i want to write select query by month.

This is my query `SELECT * FROM cubbersclosure WHERE MONTH(fromDate) = '04'`

Here `fromDate` field type is `date`

[image]

This my code:

```
var fromDate = '2019-04-01'
var fromDateMonth = new Date(fromDate);
var fromMonth = (fromDateMonth.getMonth()+ 1) < 10 ? '0' + (fromDateMonth.getMonth()+1) : (fromDateMonth.getMonth()+1);

CubbersClosure.findAll({
    where:{
        // select query with Month (04)... //fromMonth
    }
}).then(closureData=>{        
    res.send(closureData);
}).catch(error=>{
    res.status(403).send({status: 'error', resCode:200, msg:'Internal Server Error...!', data:error});
});
```

> Here `fromMonth` get only month from date, so i want to write code select query by month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure but what about try this?

```
where: {
  sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("month", sequelize.col("fromDate")), fromMonth)
}
```

Comment: I got error like `D:\my_project\choose_cubby\internal-test\app\controller\cubber\cubbers.controller.js:907
            sequelize.where()
`

Comment: So change the code like this `where: {
  $and: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("monthc", sequelize.col("fromDate")), fromMonth)
}` but again it shows error

Comment: what about replace monthc to month? there was typo

Comment: This is error `FUNCTION choose_cubby.monthc does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

for those of you looking for postgres, this is a somewhat hacky way to make this work (make sure to unit test this):

```
const results = await models.users.findAll({
   where: this.app.sequelize.fn('EXTRACT(MONTH from "createdAt") =', 3)
});
```

you can also take this a step further and query multiple attributes like so:

```
const results = await models.table.findAll({
   where: {
     [Op.and] : [
        this.app.sequelize.fn('EXTRACT(MONTH from "createdAt") =', 3),
        this.app.sequelize.fn('EXTRACT(day from "createdAt") =', 3),
     ]
   }
});
```